# Concretely, on what scenarios should I say either お世話になっています or  いつもお世話になっております?

Tags: word-choice, usage, politeness, keigo

Furthermore, what is its different in meaning between the both? When I was in training as a fresh graduate at a Japanese company, they told me to use いつもお世話になっております all the time and so I did. But after being a assigned to a department they told me to stop doing so because it sounded too weird within the team. Does it also has something to do with status?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2 equivalent forms (from your question title) should be:

お世話になっております and お世話になっています (not なります)

The former being the humble form (keigo use) and the latter being the neutral form.

This way you can see that います has been changed into the humble form おります
(if you prefer おります = います but very polite)

They told you to drop it probably because the team is more friendly. (お世話になる in itself is already quite polite, adding keigo to it would probably work with your boss but not with your colleagues)

PS: I would avoid using keigo for the moment and stick to formal japanese until keigo makes sense to you.

PPS: いつも　at the beginning adds a layer of politeness making いつもお世話になっております quite heavy and excessive in most cases.

Comment: You'd also use this phrase alot when meeting with clients or people who are influential in your spouse's life.  For instance, my wife says this all the time when she meets one of my co-workers for the first time.  Kinda like a "thank you for looking after my family"

Comment: I feel women tend to use keigo more often than men. (based on my personal experience)

Comment: Thank you I fixed the wording of the question. So in a nutshell, if I am in a friendly working environment it will be ok to drop お世話になっております.

Answer (score 2):

お世話になります is not grammatically incorrect and can be used in place of よろしくお願いします in a formal context. I've heard our suppliers use it when beginning work in our office, but it's not commonly heard.